# How to take take backup of existing Pact contracts from Pact-broker?

Tags: pact-broker

Is there a way to download all pacts and its history from PactBroker? I want to download all the pacts with any history and then upload to a new pactbroker server.  Is there a way to do that?  I didn't see a doc on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PactFlow then request them (hello@pactflow.io) directly. Otherwise, you have PostgresSQL server for Pact Broker, you can dump it or use some tools like [pgloader](https://pgloader.io/) to migrate

Comment: I figured that was one way.  Thanks